# sculpting horizontal crease on a cube shape

Tags: sculpting

I am new to sculpting, and I am having problem with creating a "brick" pattern on one of my objects.

When I try to add vertical creases to create an effect of bricks being next to each other it works only vertically. When I try to draw it horizontally it creates vertical lines one under the other...tried using "Dynotopo" and subdividing the object but it didn't help.

Any advice ?

[Google drive with the files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KpUiDOYXePQqcSpXPnwjfhf2SjCzZKdL?usp=sharing)

[image: edges]
[image: sculpting]

Comment: This would be due to bad topology. If the mesh you are sculpting does not have square/near square faces, it will turn out bad.

Comment: Is there any quick ways to adjust this? or should recreate object from the very beggining ?

Comment: could you please share your object?

Comment: I have added obj and blender files to the post.

Comment: @moonboots any clue how to covert it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the scale and it seems to work fine:

[image]

Comment: sorry, but not sure what do you mean, should i scale the edges in some specific way or is it some sculpting method ?

Comment: go in Object mode, select your object, press Ctrl A and choose Apply Scale. Your must have scaled your object in Object mode, so it was stretched in an axis, thus the bad sculpting results

Comment: Yeah, just find this. Didn't notice blender warning before. Thanks!